# Code analysis, Lost between CA1709 and CA1704

Tags: c#, code-analysis, camelcasing, pascalcasing

Because of these two KB articles, I am confused:

- [CA1704: Identifiers should be spelled correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx)
- [CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx)

I have a property named `ICD9`. My code analysis says that I have to change it to `Icd` [image]

That sounds reasonable to me. I go and change it to `Icd9` (I am not sure why it's suggesting `Icd` not `Icd9`) and I get a different warning[image]

The KB says if my acronym is three-letter long I should use Pascal casing. Isn't `Icd9` Pascal cased? I feel that `9` has causing the issue.

Comment: What is `ICD9`? Will another developer, working on your code, know what it means? If not, perhaps a longer, properly spelled, property is needed? If it's a common acronym in your industry, then add it to the custom dictionary.

Comment: ICD is a short-hand for `International Classification of Diseases` I added it to a custom dictionary file. That works for now. I will have to check on Monday if the company already has a dictionary so I add it to the existing dic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first warning is because `ICD` is not the dictionary as an acronym, so it tells you not to use all caps.

The second warning is because `ICD` is not in the dictionary at all, so it thinks it is a misspelled word.

Either add `ICD` to the [custom dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx) (as a normal word to get rid of the second warning or as a acronym and you can switch back to `ICD9` and get rid of the first warning), or try to avoid short acronym names and use a longer more descriptive name for the property that uses words that are in the dictionary.

Comment: I thought the first warning was about the casing not being found in the dic, From the fix section `Change the name so that it is cased correctly.` I agree on your comment about the next warning, I just tried to use only `Icd` and I got the same `CA1704` warning. I will give the `custom dictionary` shot and see how it goes.