# Which custom dictionary rule handles an acronym with a number?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Is there a way to make the code analysis spell-checker accept an acronym that contains a number?

I'm getting CA1704 and CA1709 warnings from code analysis in a C# application where I have identifiers with an acronym that contains a number. For example, "CheckAbc2deStatus". CA1704 wants to correct the spelling of Abc, while CA1709 wants "de" changed to "DE". I found [Code analysis, Lost between CA1709 and CA1704](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360535/code-analysis-lost-between-ca1709-and-ca1704) and have tried putting "Abc2de" in the code analysis dictionary as Words/Recognized/Word, Words/Compound/Term, and Acronyms/CasingExceptions/Acronym, but none of those entries will make the code analyzer happy. Other entries in the custom dictionary for "normal" acronyms work as expected.

Comment: What is your prefered method name? `CheckAbc2deStatus`? Also could you post your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with:

Code:

```
    public static bool CheckABC2DEStatus()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

And in the Code Analysis Dictionary:

```
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>ABC</Acronym>
      <Acronym>DE</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
```

The number seems to be treated as a word break, so I had to put the two halves in seperately.

If `CheckABC2DEStatus` isn't your preferred method name, let me know and I'll try and adjust the dictionary entry accordingly.

Comment: It's not ideal, since it allows ABC and DE to occur as separate words. If I understand the C# naming guidelines correctly, acronyms shouldn't be capitalized. I took your suggestion and tried it using "Abc" and "de", but that doesn't work. I'll just roll with the all-caps approach you gave and file a report with Microsoft.

Comment: Casing exceptions are for things that are uppercase, recognised words for others. And yes I know MS break this themselves with the Mvc namespace :-)